# Behaviour of extern in C

Tags: c, extern

If I declare `int Array[10];` in file1.c

In file2.c if I I have a function like this

```
extern int *Array;
fun()
{
    Array[0]=10; 
}
```

Is there any problem with this or not?

Comment: You should place the `extern` in a header file, and include it into both `file1.c` and `file2.c`.  In this way, the compiler will give you an error because it will see that the type of the declaration does not match the type of the `extern`.

Answer (score 8):

Yes there is a problem.

You are declaring a `Array` to be a **pointer**, while instead it's an **array**. The two are very distinct objects and here you're basically providing false information to the compiler.

Note that the C syntax to access an element is `Array[0]` in both cases, but if `Array` is a pointer variable the machine code needed will be different from if `Array` is instead an array (with the pointer there is one extra indirection).

For example if `Array1` is declared as `extern int *Array` the machine code generated by `Array1[ix] += 3` by gcc is:

```
movslq  ix(%rip), %rax        ;; Load index value from location ix
movq    Array1(%rip), %rdx    ;; Load pointer value from location Array1
leaq    (%rdx,%rax,4), %rax   ;; Compute rax as pointer + index*4
addl    $3, (%rax)            ;; Add 3 to the location pointed by rax
```

If instead `Array2` is declared as `extern int Array2[10]` the code for `Array2[ix] += 3` is simply:

```
movslq  ix(%rip), %rax        ;; Load in rax the index value from location ix
addl    $3, Array2(,%rax,4)   ;; Add 3 to the location Array2 + index*4
```

As you can see in the first case there is an extra indirection and the content of the memory at address `Array1` is read to find where the increment should be done in memory. In the second case instead only the index needs to be read to compute where the location to increment will be.

To make things more confusing in C an array "decays" into a pointer to the first element in many cases, so for example if you've a function expecting a pointer passing an array is fine because the compiler will take care of handling the difference.

The compiler must be told if an object in memory is an array or a pointer because the semantic is different; the code in the question instead does exactly this... one part of the program allocates an array and tells some part of the program that it's a pointer instead.

Answer (score 0):

The declaration `extern int *Array` does not declare an array and therefore does not match the actual definition. You have to declare:

```
extern int Array[];
```

C99(ISO/IEC 9899) §6.5.7.2 *Array declarators*

> Note the distinction between the declarations

```
extern int *x;
extern int y[];
```

> The first declares x to be a pointer to int; the second declares y to be an array of int of unspecified size(an incomplete type), the storage for which is defined elsewhere.