# ARM code apparently is not working properly for an external pointer declaration

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, arm, extern

I'm am compiling a code to ARM, and the assembly generated is not what I expected.

The following code:

```
#include <stdint.h>

extern uint8_t* a;
extern uint8_t b[];

void teste(void)
{
    *a = b[1];
    b[2] = *a;
}
```

when compiling on ARM GCC 4.7.3 and ARM GCC 4.8.3 generate the following asm:

```
00000000 <teste>:
   0:   4a04            ldr     r2, [pc, #16]   ; (14 <teste+0x14>)
   2:   4b05            ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; (18 <teste+0x18>)
   4:   6811            ldr     r1, [r2, #0]
   6:   7858            ldrb    r0, [r3, #1]
   8:   7008            strb    r0, [r1, #0]
   a:   6812            ldr     r2, [r2, #0]
   c:   7812            ldrb    r2, [r2, #0]
   e:   709a            strb    r2, [r3, #2]
  10:   4770            bx      lr
  12:   bf00            nop
         ...
```

Obs: the r2 get the address of "a", and r3 address of "b".

This asm is not what I want.
To get the asm that works properly i have to do

```
extern uint8_t a[];
```

and generate the following asm:

```
 00000000 <teste>:
    0:   4a02            ldr     r2, [pc, #8]    ; (c <teste+0xc>)
    2:   4903            ldr     r1, [pc, #12]   ; (10 <teste+0x10>)
    4:   7853            ldrb    r3, [r2, #1]
    6:   7093            strb    r3, [r2, #2]
    8:   700b            strb    r3, [r1, #0]
    a:   4770            bx      lr
         ...
```

Obs: the r2 get the address of "b", and r1 address of "a".

**NOTE**: I made a dynamic Linking to input the correct values of "a" and "b". so on the begining of the code r2 and r3 (on the first code) or r1 and r2 (on the second code) gets the right values.

To compiling I am using the following:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc.exe -c code.c -o code.o -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -O2 -mlong-calls -mword-relocations -mabi=atpcs -mfloat-abi=soft -mcaller-super-interworking 
arm-none-eabi-ld.exe -o code.elf code.o --relocatable --strip-all --discard-all --embedded-relocs
```

Does anyone know why the first method does not work properly?

The "a" is a address of a byte variable allocated in memory and therefore makes no sense to declare it as a vector.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17614468/912144) would help.

Comment: There's nothing magic about the variables being `extern` (other than the fact that you don't need to specify the number of elements in the array).  If you removed the `extern`s, and gave the array a size, you will (should) see the same code.

Comment: `extern` enters into it because it is what provides the opportunity to accidentally re-declare something defined elsewhere in a *subtly incompatible* way.  In a file where the array is properly declared as an array, you can then access it with pointer notation - the problem here is that it is declared twice, once (in another file) as an array and once (in this file) as a simple pointer, and those don't implement compatibly.

Comment: Not having seen the actual declaration, I cannot determine if it is subtly incompatible.  I assumed the type of the `extern` matches the type of the declaration.

Comment: The problem is that in C, people tend to confuse arrays and pointers because arrays behave as if they were pointers to their first element in most circumstances.  When you look under the covers, you will see that they are actually different.  If you declare a variable to be an array, but then tell another compilation unit that it is a pointer (using an `extern`), then the code will compile and link, but it will not run correctly since the two compilation units will view the same piece of memory in two fundamentally different ways.

Comment: Try `extern uint8_t* const a;`.  It may create the code you want (and be correct for the declaration that you haven't shown).  However, if it is a **single** byte, why do you even use a pointer?  It can just be `extern uint8_t a;`.  The compiler/linker figures out the address.  Are you trying to access a hardware register or is it just some regular variable in another 'C' file?

Comment: It is just another regular variable, but the declaration needs to be in another C file, because I made a realocation on this compiled code (It's generated many file like this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what `a` and `b` look like in memory:

```
     +------------------------------------------+
   a | uint8_t*             >----------------------+
     +------------------------------------------+  |
                                                   |  +---------+
     +---------+                                   +->| uint8_t | a[0] (or *a)
b[0] | uint8_t |                                      +---------+
     +---------+                                      | uint8_t | a[1] (or *(a+1))
b[1] | uint8_t |                                      +---------+
     +---------+                                      |  ...    |
b[2] | uint8_t |
     +---------+
     |  ...    |
```

Note that `b[1]`, and `b[2]` (and possibly `b[0]`) are shown as where they would logically reside, even though no actual storage will have been allocated.  Also, `a` was not initialized, so it may not be pointing at a valid memory location.

Once linked/loaded, the address of `a` and `b` will be known.  These addresses must be loaded into registers in order to access the memory where the variables reside.  In ARM, the addresses are stashed as data values, and accessed with pc-relative addressing:

```
         +------------------------------------------+
teste+0  |                                          |
         | I n s t r u c t i o n s                  |
         |                                          |
         +------------------------------------------+          +------------
teste+14 | uint8_t**         >-------------------------->    a | uint8_t * ...
         +------------------------------------------+          +------------
teste+18 | uint8_t*          >------------------------+
         +------------------------------------------+ |        +---------+
                                                      +-> b[0] | uint8_t |
                                                               +---------+
                                                          b[1] | uint8_t |
                                                               +---------+
                                                          b[2] | uint8_t |
                                                               +---------+
                                                               |  ...    |
```

By storing these constant addresses at fixed (small) offsets from the instructions, the code can use 16-bit THUMB opcodes to load them into registers.  In contrast, MIPS code will typically use a 2 32-bit instruction sequence to accomplish the same thing by loading 16-bit immediates embedded in the instructions into the upper and lower halves of the target register.

Now let's step through the instructions.

```
    0:   4a04            ldr     r2, [pc, #16]   ; (14 <teste+0x14>)
```

This line is loading the address of `a` (which was stashed in the code after the subroutine) into `r2`.

```
    2:   4b05            ldr     r3, [pc, #20]   ; (18 <teste+0x18>)
```

This line is loading the address of `b[0]` (which was stashed in the code after the subroutine) into `r3`.

```
    4:   6811            ldr     r1, [r2, #0]
```

This line is loading the pointer stored in `a` into `r1`.  So, `r1` is now pointing at some `uint8_t` (the one floating to the right in the diagram).

```
    6:   7858            ldrb    r0, [r3, #1]
```

This line loads a byte from address `r3+1` (aka `b[1]`) into `r0`.

```
    8:   7008            strb    r0, [r1, #0]
```

This stores the byte we just loaded into address `r1+0` (aka `*a`).

```
    a:   6812            ldr     r2, [r2, #0]
```

This line reloads `a` into `r2`.  This is unnecessary, since we already have this value in `r1`; however, I'm guessing you have optimization disabled.

```
    c:   7812            ldrb    r2, [r2, #0]
```

This line loads a byte from address `r2+0` (aka `*a`) into `r2`.

```
    e:   709a            strb    r2, [r3, #2]
```

This line stores the byte we just loaded into address `r3+2` (aka `b[2]`).

```
   10:   4770            bx      lr
```

And finally, we return from the subroutine.

Comment: I belive the following instructions do:
    "ldr r1, [r2, #0]"  <=>  r1 = *a (r1 contains garbage)
    "strb r0, [r1, #0]" <=> *r1 = r0 ( *(*a) = r0 )
It is this, isn't?

Comment: No, they do `r1 = a`, and `*a = r0`.  The `pc`-relative set of `ldr` instructions are loading the *addresses* of `a` and `b` into registers.  The `r2`-relative `ldr` instructions are loading the memory location determined by the address of `a`; hence, the value of `a`.

Comment: `r2` contains `&a`, and `r3` contains `&b[0]` (`&a` and `&b[0]` were stashed as 32-bit data values at offset +0x14 and +0x18 from `teste` respectively).  `ldr r1, [r2, #0]` loads the value of `a` into `r1`, so `r1` contains the address of the floating `uint8_t` off to the right.

Comment: Thanks! I was putting on "[pc, #16]" the value of a, and the correct was the &a. Thank you so much. I was thinking as the compiler treats equal pointer and vector, but no.

Answer (score 3):

Just think about the difference between an array and a pointer:

- An array is a symbol that does not have an *l-value*. As such, it cannot change during runtime.
- A pointer is a symbol that **does** have an *l-value*. As such, it **can** change during runtime.

If the compiler "thinks" that variable `a` may change during runtime, then it has to add a code for loading its value from memory before attempting to load the value from the memory address pointed by it.

If the compiler "knows" that variable `a` never changes during runtime, then it can add a code for loading the value directly from the (constant) memory address pointed by it.

BTW, although your code may compile and link without an error, I'm not sure it won't crash during runtime due to the ambiguous declaration of variable `a`, so I suggest that you simply declare `uint8_t a[1]`.

Comment: Sry, with "variable a is allocated in memory as a uint8_t" I meant that a correspond to address of a byte variable.

But the "assembly" on the first case, acts as the "a" almost if it was a double pointer by doing "ldr r1, [r2, #0]" and "strb r0, [r1, #0]". This ins't right, isnt?

Comment: OK, you changed the description, so I removed the line correcting you (at the beginning of the answer)... I think that the assembly in the first case acts as if it needs to perform two load operations instead of one, and two store operations instead of one.

Comment: The `extern type array[]` is the typical way that you must declare externs that are created from a linker file.